# Two-way lookup to return value or next closest value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a three-column table in Excel, called `Table1`, like this:

[image]

Given two values (one for each input variable), one which must be exactly equal to any of the numbers in the first column (2, 4, 6, or 8) and which must be typed in cell F2, and another one which can be any number between the least (1) and greatest (25) numbers in the second column and which must be typed in cell F3, I want to find the corresponding value in the third column. If the value typed for the second variable is not present in the second column of the table, then the output value of the next row is chosen.

For example, suppose the lookup values are `4` (for the first column) and `10` (for the second column), then the output should be `E`, since both `4` and `10` are present in the first and second columns, respectively, and the row with the output `E` corresponds to those values for the inputs.

Another example. Suppose the lookup values are `8` (for the first column) and `17` (for the second column), then the output should be `K`; it is not `J` because the latter corresponds to a value of 15 for the second column, which is strictly less than `17`; so the output is `K` because it corresponds to the value that is immediately after (or greater than) `17`, being `20`.

### My attempt

To limit the available values the user can choose, I could create data-validated cells. For choosing the values in the first column, the data validation would by of type `list` and be equal to `2, 4, 6, 8`; such cell would be F2. Like this:

[image]

For choosing the values in the second column, the data validation would be of the type `whole number`, with `minimum` value of `1` and `maximum` value of `25`. Like this:

[image]

Now the formulas for the lookup. After googling, I found out that performing a look-up task with two input criteria is known as a *two-way lookup*. Using the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions, I managed to perform the two-way lookup, unfortunately the formula only allows exact matches, so it works fine when the first and second input values are `4` and `10`, but not when they're `8` and `17`. The formula is the following, and it is in cell F4:

```
{=INDEX(Table1[Output], MATCH($F$2 & "|" & $F$3, Table1[1st input variable] & "|" & Table1[2nd input variable], 0))}
```

(The presence of curly braces means that we must enter the formula with `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` instead of just `Enter`.)

Here's a screenshot for the first successful example:

[image]

Here's a screenshot for the second failed example:

[image]

I tried changing the third parameter of the MATCH function from 0 to 1, but it returns `J` (which corresponds to 15 in the second column, but 17 < 15) instead of `K` (which corresponds to 20, since 17 > 20 and 20 is the closest value to 17 that is immediately after it.)

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: You maybe looking for something like: `=INDEX(C2:C13,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A13=F2)*(B2:B13>=F3),),0))`

Comment: It worked; thanks!

Comment: @JvdV Hi again. Is there a way a way to modify your formula (which isn't an array formula as in requiring Ctrl + Shift + Enter, and doesn't use Excel 365 formulas) for the following problem? The problem is similar to the one of this question-post, except that 1) there's only one input variable, 2) the column for input variable has unique values, and 3) the values in the input column are in ascending order. I still want to find the next higher value at the input if the lookup value is not present in the table. **[Here I show how I'd like the formula to behave](https://imgur.com/a/C3qOUZY)**.

Comment: I tried modifying your formula to `=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A5>=F2),),0))`, but it doesn't work. If I "trick" Excel by adding a only-TRUE vector as in `=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A5>=F2) * {TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE},),0))`, then it works. But this doesn't seem efficient when you have hundreds of rows. Is there a way around this? Sorry to ask this through comments.

Comment: Okay, I found a solution. By using F9 on each part of your formula, I noticed the error was that, when using `=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A5>=F2),),0))` (the formula with error), the part `INDEX((A2:A5>=F2),)` evaluates to `{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE}`, and then `MATCH(1,{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE},0)` evaluates to `#N/A`. On the other hand, when using `=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A5>=F2) * {TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE},),0))` (the formula that works), the part `INDEX((A2:A5>=F2) * {TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE},)` evaluates to `{0;0;1;1}`, and then `MATCH(1,{0;0;1;1},0)` evaluates to `3`. So, I simply [...]

Comment: [...] need to convert the FALSEs to 0 and the TRUEs to 1. *[A quick Google search](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5880-excel-convert-boolean-true-false-to-number-text.html#:~:text=You%20can%20multiply%20the%20return,1%20and%20FALSE%20to%200.)* showed I can do that by multiplying the FALSEs/TRUEs by 1. Hence, I tried the formula `=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A5>=F2) * 1,),0))`, and it works perfect. Thank you a lot anyways for the original formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have Excel 365 then you can use the new `Filter`-function:

`=INDEX(FILTER(Table1[output],(Table1[1st Input variable]=first)*(Table1[2nd input variable]>=second),"no result"),1)`

I named F3 "first" and F4 "second".

`FILTER` returns all output values where

- column A = value from F3
- column B >= the value from F4.

`INDEX` selects the first row of the FILTER-result

Comment: With ms365 you can force implicit intersection (turn of spilling) by adding `@`. Therefor, `=@FILTER(.......>=second)` should do.

Comment: Perfect - so much to learn with the new functions - thanks!

Comment: I don't have Excel 365, is there another way?

Comment: Does this work: `=INDEX(Table1[output],MATCH(1,(Table1[1st]=first)*(Table1[2nd]>=second),0))` - as I don't have an older version of Excel it's hard to test that ... Maybe you have to enter it as array formula (Strg + Enter) >> this is the same like from JvdV, didn't saw that comment

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Comment: @Ike, it indeed is the same. The 2nd nested index in my comment is only there to prevent the users to have to CSE the formula =)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but you can round the second input to what you need. In your example, all your values are multiples of 5. Just create an exception for number 1 with an IF.

Here's what I tried:

[image]

```
={INDEX($C$1:$C$12;MATCH(F7&IF(ROUNDUP(G7/5;0)=1;1;ROUNDUP(G7/5;0)*5);$A$1:$A$12&$B$1:$B$12;0))}
```

**Notice it's an array formula**.